# Noisy image from OV2640

Tags: esp32

I have designed a custom PCB with an ESP32 and an OV2640 camera module. The image contains some noise and I don´t understand where the noise is coming from.

[image]

My suggestion is that the data lines from the camera module to the ESP32 are too long (shortest 45 and longest 54 mm), but I´m not sure. And I´m unsure how I can solve this issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The camera interface here is parallel. So data lines should have the same length in order to make sure datas are reached at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you think the problem is the traces length you might want to enlarge the clock period in order for the data edges to complete their transients.

Also, slow down the image capture.